# TypeDoc: How to link to internal / provided types like Array and Promise

Tags: typescript, documentation, typedoc

I can't figure out how to link / reference the provided TypeScript types, for example from TypeScript's own `lib.es5.d.ts`.

For example I have a `stringSplice` function that basically works the same as the native `Array.prototype.splice` function. Though I'd like to include a `@link` to it.

I tried lot's of combinations, but every time I just got a `Failed to resolve link to xyz`

```
/**
 * Works like {@link Array.prototype.splice}
 * Works like {@link Array.splice}
 * Works like {@link Array:splice}
 * Works like {@link Array::splice}
 * Works like {@link Array#splice}
 */
export const stringSplice =
  (str: string, start = 0, deleteCount?: number, replacement = "") => {
    start = start < 0 ? mod(start, str.length) : start;
    deleteCount =  Math.max(deleteCount ?? str.length - start, 0);
    return str.slice(0, start) + replacement + str.slice(start + deleteCount);
  };
```

It this possible at all? Or maybe I need a plugin?

---

EDIT: My TypeDoc config is kinda empty. It just includes support for monorepo

```json
{
  "entryPointStrategy": "packages",
  "entryPoints": ["packages/*"],
  "out": "./docs",
  "plugin": ["typedoc-plugin-resolve-crossmodule-references"]
}
```

Comment: typedoc-plugin-mdn-links would be the way to do this -- but it needs an update to support resolving external links in `@link` tags ([#4](https://github.com/Gerrit0/typedoc-plugin-mdn-links/issues/4))

Comment: @Gerrit0 I found some workaround using `externalSymbolLinkMappings` with `global: { Array: "https://..." }` and then use it with `{@link !Array}`. This will indeed render the correct link, but it outputs `!Array` instead of simply `Array` (without the exclamation mark). I also tried using a named namespace like `typescript`, this then renders `typescript!Array` instead of just `Array`